# How to tell httrack not to append index.html to links

Tags: mirroring, httrack

When mirroring a site with a link like `www.example.com/some/where/` httracks changes it to `www.example.com/some/where/index.html` in the local copy.

**Is there an option for avoiding the appended index.html?**

PS. I am fully aware that the index.html is needed for local browsing of the site, but the thing is that the mirror is going to replace the site on the server. It's a database driven site that is going to be replaced by a static version since it is not going to get updated anymore. But I wish it to be identical to a snapshot of the original site.

If it is not possible I will need to use sed to remove the index.html parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using sed:

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec sed -i 's%index.html%%g' {} \;
```

It finds all files ending with .html in the current sub directory and runs a sed command on them that replaces all occurences of index.html with nothing, ie. deletes it.

Comment: Could you provide some explanation about what your code does?

Comment: It finds all files ending with .html in the current sub directory and runs a sed command on them that replaces all occurences of index.html with nothing, ie. deletes it.

Comment: **Note** If it will find 3rd party link in your html which was somewhere e.g. in content of the article it will break that link too. Sed won't care what "text" it looks into, it will just remove all index.html in whatever context. in <a> or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Just add option `-K` and it will skip those index.html in URLs. Yet you need to make sure your host can resolve URLs w/o index.html

E.g.:

```sh
httrack https://example.com/ -K
```

[image]

https://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html